# Convert single column file into multiple columns

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, multiple-columns

Basically, I want to convert one column file into multiple column file specified by number of rows.

I do not want to reinvent the wheel. I want to make sure if there is a unix command / or standard way of doing this before writing a custom script.

For example, let's say I have the following file:

```
$cat input.txt
tom
jack
kim
bart
foo
bar
```

I want to turn this into 3 row file

```
$ cat input.txt | my_script --every=3 --delimiter=tab
tom bart
jack foo
kim bar
```

or 2 row file with the different delimter:

```
$ cat input.txt | my_script --every=2 --delimiter=,
tom,kim,foo
jack,bart,bar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`

```
 awk -v row=2 '{A[(NR-1)%row]=A[(NR-1)%row]$0" ";next}END{for(i in A)print A[i]}' file
```

output:

```
tom  bart 
jack foo 
kim  bar
```

here specify no of row you want in `raw` variable. eg: `row=3` for three rows.

Try like this for if you want only break column in specific rows

`cat file | xargs -n2`

Here 2 for each row contain 2 column, You can use what you want.

Comment: Op wants `tom bart;jack foo;kim bar` that gives `tom jack;kim bart;foo bar`

Answer (score 14):

What about using `xargs`?

two records per line:

```
$ xargs -n2 < file
tom jack
kim bart
foo bar
```

three records per line:

```
$ xargs -n3 < file
tom jack kim
bart foo bar
```

Comment: This fills rows first, which isn't what the question's example is demonstrating.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `paste` command in UNIX for converting the file into multiple columns. By default, tab is the delimiter. To change the delimiter, use `-d` option

Command: convert one column file into two columns

```
paste - - < input.txt
```

output:

```
tom  bart 
jack foo 
kim  bar
```

Command: convert one column file into two columns with `,` as a delimiter

```
paste - - -d, < input.txt
```

Output:

```
tom,bart 
jack,foo 
kim,bar
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried several of the solutions provided above including `paste - -` and `xargs -n2`, but none of these satisfy the OP requirement of having **half of the list in one column and the other half in the other column**. I did not try the `awk` solution, as it looked clunky, wordy, and there was not much explanation on what the code is doing.

After some digging, I found this gives a short and elegant solution using `pr`:

```sh
echo "tom
jack
kim
bart
foo
bar" > my_file

cat my_file | pr -2 -t -s
```

Returns:

```sh
tom bart
jack    foo
kim bar
```

If you want it comma-delimited:

```sh
cat my_file | pr -2 -t -s,
```

Returns:

```sh
tom,bart
jack,foo
kim,bar
```

From the `pr` manpage:

> ```
> -s char
>       Separate text columns by the single character char instead of by the appropriate number of <space>s (default for char is the <tab> character).
>
> -t    Print neither the five-line identifying header nor the five-line trailer usually supplied for each page.  Quit printing after the last line of each file without
>       spacing to the end of the page.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

```
awk '{a[(NR-1)%n]=a[(NR-1)%n]==""?$1:a[(NR-1)%n] OFS $1}END{for (i=0;i<n;i++) print a[i]}' n=3 OFS="\t" file

tom     bart
jack    foo
kim     bar


awk '{a[(NR-1)%n]=a[(NR-1)%n]==""?$1:a[(NR-1)%n] OFS $1}END{for (i=0;i<n;i++) print a[i]}' n=2 OFS="," file

tom,kim,foo
jack,bart,bar
```

Answer (score 0):

As a start, you can use sed to get the proper data, e.g.

```
$ sed -n '1~2p' input
tom
kim
foo

$ sed -n '2~2p' input
jack
bart
bar
```

Then there are many ways to convert a column into a row. To name a few:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < file

awk -vORS=' ' 1 file

paste -sd" " file
```

Comment: This is actually not what I want. For the two column example, I want tom, jack, kim to be in the same column